# WordPress $wpdb update balance

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

can you help me searching answer for a while but I can't find it. I want to update my mysql entry 'balance', balance 90 after adding 10, balance = 100 (90 + 10 = 100), i am doing this

```
$add_credits = $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'balance' => '10' ), array ( 'email' => $email ) );
```

but it only updating like 90 + 10 = 90. How to do 90 + 10 = 100? Very thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $table_name 
    SET balance = balance+10
    WHERE email = '".$email."'

    "
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with normal UPDATE query and not with $wpdb update query

```
UPDATE table SET balance= (90+ 10)) WHERE some_condition;
```

You can override that with the format parameter, but that only allows %d, %f, and %s (integer, float, string). It doesn't allow operations on columns like balance+10.